# How to construct json object structure from the fields in inner HTML divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML and I need to construct the JSON for the input fields. I need to make the DIVs marked with 'collect' as objects in JSON. Objects might have other objects or fields (analogous to DIVs with inner DIVs and Input fields). I am using JQuery. I have some code that I have developed but doesn't result in what I want. If needed I can post that code. Also, If needed, I can move div classes like 'p1', 'p2' etc.. into **rel** attribute.

Thanks for your help.

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="p1 collect">
   <div class="somestyleclass">
    <div class="p2 collect">
        <input type="text" name="i1" value="1">
        <input type="text" name="i2" value="2">
    </div>
    <div class="p3 collect">
        <input type="text" name="i3" value="3">
        <input type="text" name="i4" value="4">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="somestyleclass">
    <div class="p4 collect">
        <div class="somestyleclass">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <div class="p5 collect">
                <input type="text" name="i5" value="5">
                <input type="text" name="i6" value="6">
            </div>
            <div class="p5 collect">
                <input type="text" name="i5" value="7">
                <input type="text" name="i6" value="8">
            </div>
            <div class="p5 collect">
                <input type="text" name="i5" value="9">
                <input type="text" name="i6" value="10">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
   </div>

</div>
```

**Result JSON:**

```
{
    "p1": {
        "p2": {
            "i1":"1", "i2":"2"
        },
        "p3": {
            "i3":"3", "i4":"4"
        },
        "p4": [
            {
                "p5":{
                    "i5":"5", "i6":"6"
                }
            },
            {
                "p5":{
                    "i7":"7", "i8":"8"
                }
            },
            {
                "p5":{
                    "i9":"9", "i10":"10"
                }
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this need to be generic? Or just for the HTML you posted?

Comment: this needs to be generic. I am also trying to post what I have in JSFiddle and add a link.

Comment: I think `fieldset`s with `name`s would be more appropriate than divs with classes

Comment: This link has one of the versions of the code i am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/GNTG6/  I have another version which I will clean up and post